# What is the relation between Jim and Richard?

Tags: character, sherlock

In the [SHERLOCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_%28TV_series%29) episode "[The Reichenbach Fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reichenbach_Fall)," Sherlock and John Watson ran into James (Jim) Moriarty in the home of a journalist determined to expose Sherlock as a fraud. Sherlock was furious and Moriarty acted cowardly and very un-James-Moriarty-like. He claimed to be an actor named Richard Brook whom Sherlock had hired to act as a nemesis in his adventures to bolster the public opinion/image of Sherlock. "Richard" claimed *there was no Moriarty.*

Is Richard really James, or is James really Richard? Did Sherlock actually pay an actor to be Moriarty? Is there a real Moriarty?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're even asking. Can you give us some additional context. There's no character in the entire show named "Richard".

Comment: @Catija Yes, there is. I think he's asking about "Richard Brook," the "actor" in the show who claimed Moriarty was an invention that Sherlock payed him to portray (in the episode [The Reichebach Fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reichenbach_Fall)). And if Moriarty exists at all, or is it as "Richard" claimed?

Comment: @MeatTrademark ok... But the op hasn't clarified that. We have no way of knowing what's being asked. You even say "I think".

Comment: **I'm 95% sure.** I usually try to say "I think" or "it seems" instead of bold declaratives. If you forget there was a "Richard," I see how it's confusing. It seems like a straightforward, although possible ESL, question to me. My two cents: It certainly seems like Jim and Richard are the same person, and he *is* Moriarty, but I can see how some might question it.

Comment: *Did Sherlock pay Richard Brook to act the role of James Moriarty?* If you've seen the episode Reichenbach Fall, this question makes perfect sense.

Comment: This question could really use a little more context of what you're actually talking about, starting with the actual movie or TV show episode and the characters you mean specifically.

Comment: I agree that it's a clunky question, but I knew *immediately* what the question was, because I watch Sherlock. All the salient points are present. Jim (James) Moriarty posed as Richard. Richard claims Sherlock invented the acting role of Jim. He claims there is no Jim. All in one scene. Maybe *don't VTC if you don't watch the show.* How does everyone forget this scene? From arguably the most intense episode? Napoleon and Catija, have you seen the episode? If so, how is it so unclear? If not, how could you know it's unclear? Not sure why, but this bums me out.

Comment: @MeatTrademark If you understand the question so well, feel free to help the others do so, too, by editing the question a little. There's even a badge for editing questions you answered. (By the way, I have seen the episode, now that I have come to know which episode is actually talked about by reading the answer. I still have a hard time figuring out what this question is talking about.) But fine, if noone who understands the question wants to improve it, I guess I'll have to do so once I have the time to look into it...

Comment: ...Yet this isn't about me alone getting what the question is about, but simply about providing a well fleshed-out question, for *everyone*.

Comment: I've given it a go. Hope it makes sense. And as this wasn't an ID-This Q, It bugged me that I seemed to be alone in understanding it. And, I think it's a useful addition to the archive. At least now, hopefully. It probably helps I've seen this ep about 5 times... :)

Comment: @MeatTrademark Thank you very much for the edit. +2

Comment: @close-and-downvoters You might want to take another look at the updated question.

Answer (score 6):

No. Jim Moriarty is not Richard Brook. This is evident from the confrontation between Sherlock and Jim on the rooftop.

> JIM: Did you almost start to wonder if I was real? Did I nearly get you?
>
> SHERLOCK: Richard Brook.
>
> JIM: Nobody seems to get the joke, but you do.
>
> SHERLOCK: Of course.
>
> JIM: Attaboy.
>
> SHERLOCK: Rich Brook in German is Reichen Bach – the case that made my name.
>
> JIM (in a fake American accent): Just tryin’ to have some fun.

Jim Moriarty wanted to kill Sherlock right from the very beginning (Season 1, Episode 3) but he got a better *distraction* and left him off. This time he weaved an intricate *fairytale* around Sherlock. He wanted Sherlock to die in disgrace henceforth he *became* Richard Brook so that he could falsify Sherlock's ingenuity.

Also, right in the next episode (Season 3, episode 1), the court verdict is out which goes like:

> REPORTER 1 (into his crew’s camera): ... that after extensive police investigations, Richard Brook did indeed prove to be the creation of James Moriarty ...
>
> REPORTER 2 (into a different camera): ... amidst unprecedented scenes, there was uproar in court as Sherlock Holmes was vindicated and cleared of all suspicion ...
>
> REPORTER 3: ... but sadly, all this comes too late for the detective who became something of a celebrity two years ago ...

Source for transcript: [Ariane DeVere](http://arianedevere.livejournal.com/)

Comment: In season 2 episode 3, moriarty dies but in season 3 episode 3, moriarty appears from nowhere. can you tell me a possible explanation?

Comment: Well that's a tough one. But some inference can be drawn from the Abominable Bride episode. The bride apparently shoots herself in public, then kills her husband and then Sir Eustace. Probably it's Moriarty's men who are trying to keep him alive.

Comment: Yes that may be one. But, I think Moriarty is dead. Those "Did you miss me?" on the TV can be broadcasted by Moriarty's men.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, **No**. From the episode [The Reichenbach Fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reichenbach_Fall). Sherlock did not pay the actor "Richard Brook" to pretend to be an arch-nemesis to further his profile and create newsworthy exploits. James Moriarty was pretending to be an actor.

*Evidence:*

He makes faces at Sherlock during the confrontation in the apartment.

He shows up later in the episode, especially note the rooftop climax.

Later in the series he shows up on screens saying "Miss Me?"

There is nothing but Moriarty *as* Richard's word to go on. That, and an easily faked CV and headshots, etc.

Lastly, the fact that Sherlock, as a "high-functioning sociopath," shot a man in cold blood ([in the same episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Last_Vow) Moriarty makes his return via the aforementioned televised "Miss me?" stunt) hardly seems like the action of someone who needs to outsource for exploits and fame (or infamy).

*Conclusion:*

Moriarty just did this just to screw with Sherlock, and to cast doubt on his veracity and integrity in the eyes of those around him. In short, Moriarty being a true nemesis.

Comment: I also think the cockiness of Moriarty waiting on the roof while listening to "Stayin' Alive" is further evidence that Moriarty is real.